# Clarity Design Grid

Tags: bootstrap-4, vmware-clarity, flexboxgrid

When I'm developing in the responsive view of a browser (e.g. Firefox: iphone X) everything fits perfectly, but when I change to the iphone X browser (Safari or Chrome) the content goes behind the browser bottom menu, and I need to scroll to see the content.

Is the Grid  not taking in consideration the viewport size minus the bottom menu size of the browser?

Any hint to overcome this subject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a sample to review? It can be difficult to know what to suggest by this alone. Stackblitz is great for making demos https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: Thanks, I will prepare the code to run in Stackblitz,

Comment: Please see the link for Stackblitz: https://clarity-design-grid-responsive.stackblitz.io/ . If we open the link in the desktop browser the bottom menu bar will be visible, but in a mobile (iphoneXS, 7, ...) the menu bar is hidden by the browser bottom menu.

Comment: To access to the code https://stackblitz.com/@lnkpaulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have a workaround, not the ideal solution but solves the issue.

The challenge in the mobile environment, to have a fixed bottom menu always visible, is due to the property `height: 100vh` in the `.main-container` wrapper. Then what was the workaround?

Was added in `styles.css` to define a reference height `height: 100%`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and in `app.component.css`

```css
.main-coontainer {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

... and it's done. See the example at  [stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-design-grid-responsive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-design-grid-responsive).